# Change dynamically CF7 Stripe module amount depending on user selected price

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, contact-form-7

With the Contact Form 7’s [Stripe integration module](https://contactform7.com/stripe-integration/)  I would like to customize the form tag amount depending on the user selected checkbox value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPrice" value="10€">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkboxPrice" value="30€">
```

**[stripe currency:eur amount:checkboxPriceValue "Proceed to checkout" "Pay"]**

As mentionned [here](https://contactform7.com/2021/10/16/customizing-stripe-payment-parameters/) it's possible to dynamically replace the tripe tag amount depending on the user selected choice but i'm not able to do it.

```
add_filter(
    'wpcf7_stripe_payment_intent_parameters',
 
    function ( $params ) {
 
        // Get the WPCF7_Submission object
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
 
        // Retrieve the currency from the 'your-currency' field value
        $currency = (array) $submission->get_posted_data( 'your-currency' );
        $currency = (string) array_shift( $currency );
        $params['currency'] = strtolower( $currency );
 
        // Calculate the amount
        $amount = checkboxPriceValue;
        $params['amount'] = $amount;
 
        $receipt_email = $submission->get_posted_data( 'your-email' );
 
        if ( is_email( $receipt_email ) ) {
            $params['receipt_email'] = $receipt_email;
        }
 
        // See https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create
        // for the full list of available parameters
 
        return $params;
    },
 
    10, 1
);
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i get the correct amount depending on the user selected checkbox on submit and it's succesfully passed to Stripe !

Here is the Stripe shortcode I use :

```
**[stripe currency:eur amount:1000 "Go to checkout" "Pay !"]**
```

Now checkbox is used to define dynamically Stripe price, only two choice for me with this shortcode :

```
**[checkbox* checkbox-price class:checkbox-price-unit use_label_element exclusive default:1 "10€" "18€"]**



$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox-price]').on('change', function(){

            let $checkboxPriceItem = $('input:checkbox[name=checkbox-price]'),
                $stripeAmount      = $('#stripeAmount');

            if ( $checkboxPriceItem[0].checked ) {
                $stripeAmount.val('1000');
            } else if ( $checkboxPriceItem[1].checked ) {
                $stripeAmount.val('1800');
            }   
});

// The stripe field with the price value
<input type="hidden" name="stripeAmount" value="1000" id="stripeAmount">

// Customize stripe price 
add_filter('wpcf7_stripe_payment_intent_parameters',
 
    function ( $params ) {
 
        // Get the WPCF7_Submission object
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
  
        // Retrieve the currency from the 'your-currency' field value
        //$currency = (array) $submission->get_posted_data( 'your-currency' );
        //$currency = (string) array_shift( $currency );

        // Put your currency here in uppercase
        $currency = 'EUR'; 
        $params['currency'] = strtolower( $currency );

        // get value from input name=stripeAmount
        $amount = (array) $submission->get_posted_data( 'stripeAmount' );
        $amount = (string) array_shift( $amount );

        // Optional, add security so that user can't change this value with JS 
        if ( $amount == 1000 || $amount == 1800) {
          $params['amount'] = $amount;
        } else {
          return false;
        }

        // Retrieve the buyer's email from the 'your-email' field value
        $receipt_email = $submission->get_posted_data( 'your-email' );
 
        if ( is_email( $receipt_email ) ) {
            $params['receipt_email'] = $receipt_email;
        }
 
        // See https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create
        // for the full list of available parameters
 
        return $params;
    },
 
    10, 1
);
```